# Question about SO questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I know I'm way out of topic here, but I'm not sure I really can help it.

My question is, can I post questions to SO with an answer for the sole purpose of helping future SO users that have the same question?

Keep in mind that while at it, other users can post alternative (and possibly better answers), although there might be some bias.

**NB:** I've alerted the mods to decide where this question should be best kept, no need for further arguing about this, thanks.

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ :)

Comment: Sam - I read it's about the stack exchange engine. My initial thoughts were submitting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You should read the FAQs ;)

> Please look around to see if your
>   question has already been asked (and
>   maybe even answered!) before you ask.
>   It’s also perfectly fine to ask and
>   answer your own question, as long as
>   you pretend you’re on Jeopardy: phrase
>   it in the form of a question.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Lucifer - Thanks didn't quite notice that clause (yes, I did read the FAQ ;))